# Why isn't `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` a builtin environment variable of Bash?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

From [*An introduction to GCC*](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_25.html):

> The simplest way to set the load path is through the environment
>   variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. For example, the following commands set
>   the load path to `/opt/gdbm-1.8.3/lib` so that `libgdbm.so` can be
>   found:
>
> ```
> $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gdbm-1.8.3/lib
> $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> $ ./a.out
> Storing key-value pair... done.
> ```

Is it correct that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` isn't a builtin environment variable of Bash? Otherwise, there is no need to `export` it.

A Bash shell uses `PATH` to locate an external program, and `PATH` is a builtin environment variable of Bash.

A Bash shell uses `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to locate the shared libraries which a program relies on to run, so why isn't `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` a builtin environment variable of Bash?

Answer (score 10):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` isn’t used by the shell, it’s used by the dynamic linker. See [`man ld.so`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) for details.

If you don’t export it, the linker won’t see it and won’t be able to act on it.

Comment: Additionally, there is no such thing as "a built in environment variable". It's either a shell variable or a environment variable, and environment variables are inherited by child processes.

Comment: Thanks. How do the shell and `ld` work together to start running a program which needs a shared library? Does the shell first fork a child process to run `ld` which does its job to load the shared library somewhere in the library, and then the shell fork a second child process to run the program with the loaded shared library?

Comment: They don’t work together. The shell asks the kernel to run the program, and the kernel loads the dynamic linker (which is the program’s “interpreter”).

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean the dynamic linker `ld` interpret (i.e. run) both the shared library and the program which needs the library? Then when a bash shell runs a program which doesn't need a shared library, is `ld` also the interpreter which run the program? Is `ld` always the interpreter to run a program, regardless how it is run? Is `ld.so` an executable or a shared library itself, because the extension name leads to the latter while it is supposed to be the former?

Comment: I suggest you read [How programs get run](https://lwn.net/Articles/630727/) and [How programs get run: ELF binaries](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/) to get a better feel for what’s involved. The *kernel* runs programs, but when it’s asked to run a dynamically-linked ELF binary it delegates to the dynamic linker. `ld.so` (or whatever variant your system actually uses) is both an executable and a shared library.